# Xfce screenshooter and clipboard manager

Tags: xfce, clipboard, screenshot

I moved from Xfce4 to i3 recently but I still use `xfce4-screenshooter`. It works properly and I had no problems with it except that I can't save to clipboard.

On [this page](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/screenshooter/usage) it is written:

> **Copy to the clipboard**
>
> The **Copy to the clipboard** option allows you to
>   paste the screenshot in another application, such as a word processor.
>   This option is only available when a clipboard manager is running.

Althrough I didn't have `clipman` while I was using Xfce, I was able to use option *copy to clipboard*. I want to know what program (clipboard manager) should I run at the start of every i3 session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this very same migration myself! I found that I needed to install `xfce4-clipman`, and then run it on startup by putting `exec --no-startup-id xfce4-clipman &` in my `~/.i3/config`.

I'm not sure why I needed to do this manually though, because I also did not have clipman before my switch to i3, and yet the clipboard option worked. Maybe there's another daemon serving that function?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the `xfce4-clipman` (arch linux + i3) where it keeps crashing shortly after use (but it does work for a short time) with this message: `(xfce4-clipman:23285): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 10:20:47.172: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed`

Answer (score 2):

I've done the same migration as well and faced the same issue.
I was not satisfied with `xfce4-clipman` showing as a tray icon even tough it works. I also bound my `Print` key with `xfce4-screenshooter` in region mode but it won't let me cancel with escape if that was a missclick. Instead I went with `gnome-screenshot` whose `--clipboard` works out of the box.
My i3 config for this binding is:

```
# -c = copy to clipboard
# -a = area/region mode
bindsym Print exec gnome-screenshot -ca
```

Now I just have to press my print key, select the area I want to screenshot and it will be copied to my clipboard without having to click anything.

Comment: latest xfce4-screenshooter on Arch still has problem, cannot cancel file dialog, infinite loop. Thanks for documenting this, I thought it was just my setup. Switched to Gnome too.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to installing and running a clipboard manager, a pipe to `xclip` will do:

```
xfce4-screenshooter --fullscreen --mouse --save /dev/stdout | xclip -i -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

If this is to be used as an application shortcut in the XFCE keyboard settings, the command line above must to be interpreted by a shell in order to build the pipe:

```
sh -c 'xfce4-screenshooter --fullscreen --mouse --save /dev/stdout | xclip -i -selection clipboard -t image/png'
```

The fullscreen and mouse options are my use case, other options (such as `--window` instead of `--fullscreen`) also work of course.

**Caveat:** The original question was about a migration from XFCE to i3. I encountered the same problem within XFCE (as have others apparently), and my search for solutions only led to suggestions involving a clipboard manager. I thought I should publish my solution in a suitable place and this seems to be the best one, but I have not tested this in i3.

Comment: For me this broke on a stock ubuntu 22.04 install suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

Command to install xfce4-clipman plugin in Arch:

```
sudo pacman -S xfce4-clipman-plugin
```